# How to open/close bootstrapSwitch by js

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function click(){
 $("#check_box").bootstrapSwitch('checked',true);
}
 </script >


<input class="bootstrap-switch" type="checkbox" data-size="small" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="default" id="check_box">

<input type="submit" onclick="click()">
```

How to open/close bootstrap Switch by js.
I can't open by click button.

Comment: add a working snippet and explain your question in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the button state by doing:

```
$("#check_box").bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
```

See the [docs](http://bootstrapswitch.com/methods.html) for more information.